# JavaScript: can't access a childNode of one iteration of a nodeList

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

Given this markup:

```
<ul id="navtabs">
  <li><a onClick="someFunction();" href="#">Link</a></li>
  <li><a onClick="someFunction();" href="#">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this function:

```
function someFunction(){
  navList=document.getElementById('navtabs').childNodes;
  for(i=0;i<navList.length;i++){
    navList[i].childNodes[0].className='fgf';
  }
}
```

my expectaction is that the class of each anchor is changed, however, when the function runs I get:

```
Error: navList[i].childNodes[0] is undefined
```

When I use:

```
navList[i].className='fgf';
```

in lieu of the above code, the class name of the list item is changed as expected.

How can i access the childNode of the childNode through the loop as seen in the above function?

Thank you.

Comment: I would suspect you are hitting an empty text node in that loop - it has no children so you get the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`childNodes` is likely giving you text nodes as well as dom elements, which is why you're getting that error.  In your loop, `navList[i]` is at times a text node with no children of its own, which is of course why `navList[i].childNodes[0]` is `undefined`

Instead of using `childNodes` you could do

```
navList=document.getElementById('navtabs').children;
```

to just get the child **elements**.  But I would recommend being even more specific with `getElementsByTagName`

```
function someFunction() {
    navList = document.getElementById('navtabs').getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(i = 0; i < navList.length; i++){
        navList[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0].className='fgf';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `<a>` element children-

```
function someFunction(){
  var navList=document.getElementById('navtabs').getElementsByTagName('a');
  for(i=0;i<navList.length;i++){
    navList[i]className='fgf';
  }
}
```